# PHP - echo inside variable $message in mailsender

Tags: php

Helo, I have a problem with a variable `$folder` inside PHP echo code for mailsender. Everything is ok, but the code doesn't display an image, probably I made a mistake here.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "mail@my.mail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = "MYSELF"; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = "A";
    $last_name = "B";
    $subject = "Hello!";
    $subject2 = "X";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $message= "
    <tr>
        <td><b>Subname</b></br>".$_POST["Subname"]."</td>
        <td rowspan='10'></br><img src='".$folder."'width='200' height='200'></td>
    </tr>";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
?>
```

In normal PHP code I have this and image is showed properly, but I move the "echo" to `$message` in mailsender it doesn't work.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $folder = "upload/".$file_name;

        move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $folder);
        echo "<img src='$folder' width='200' height='200'>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You have not declared `$folder` in your first example.

Comment: `$folder` will need to be a full URL - `http://example.com/upload/foo.jpg`.

Comment: Hmm.. something like <img src='http://mysite/".$folder."'width='200' height='200'>

Comment: Declare  $folder variable  and assign the value it . 

Such as 

$folder = $yourdomain."upload/".$file_name;

Answer (score 0):

You your second PHP code, `$folder` is pointing to a directory and it works correctly.

But for it to work in your `$message`, $folder needs to be a link to the image. Something like `http://example.com/image.png`

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    $folder = "http://example.com/image.png";

    $to = "mail@my.mail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = "MYSELF"; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = "A";
    $last_name = "B";
    $subject = "Hello!";
    $subject2 = "X";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $message= "
    <tr>
        <td><b>Subname</b></br>".$_POST["Subname"]."</td>
        <td rowspan='10'></br><img src='".$folder."'width='200' height='200'></td>
    </tr>";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
?>
```